# How to apply max length limitation to a column which accepts text of any language in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I'm working with Java & Oracle.

I have a column `col1` with the limit of 100 characters and which can accept characters of any language. For example, it can store, 'Test'(English) as the value as well as 'ทดสอบ'(Thai) as the value.

The problem I'm facing is, if I make `col1` having the datatype `varchar2(100)`, it works for English characters, but it doesn't work for the Thai characters.

This happens because when I look at the Thai character size it is only 5. But when it gets converted to Bytes at the time of being stored in the database, it gets converted to characters of higher length (>5). So, when I enter some sample Thai text of 48 characters only, it turns out to be 136 bytes. And hence, my database doesn't accept the value, throws DataTruncationError.

How can I handle this case from the database perspective? What datatype should I use for `col1`, in order to ensure 100 characters of any language max limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the length in bytes or the length in characters. In this case you want to make sure the column accepts 100 characters so you declare: varchar2(100 char) instead of varchar2(100 byte). If you omit char or byte the column is defined using the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS as it it set for the database.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams149.htm

Comment: Isn't it like, when I say `varchar2(100)`, by default, it is `varchar2(100 char)`?

Comment: Was just adding a remark about NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **CLOB and NCLOB Datatypes**

The CLOB and NCLOB datatypes store up to 4 gigabytes of character data in the database. CLOBs store database character set data and NCLOBs store Unicode national character set data. For varying-width database character sets, the CLOB value is stored in the database using the two-byte Unicode character set, which has a fixed width. Oracle translates the stored Unicode value to the character set requested on the client or on the server, which can be fixed-width or varying width. When you insert data into a CLOB column using a varying-width character set, Oracle converts the data into Unicode before storing it in the database.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c13datyp.htm#3234

Comment: How can I specify a column to have CLOB or NCLOB datatype and 100 characters max limitation? Can you give me some example query?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1(FIELD1 varchar2(3000) constraint FIELD_CHK_LENGTH check(length(FIELD1)<=4));
```